# Speech Recognition Engine not recognizing speech

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

im trying to create a dynamic speech recognizer but for some reason it is not working. i have tried to use the emulaterecognize function and the application works fine but it doesn't work when i speak. this means that the list of words are properly added and the speech recognized event functions properly but it is never being called without the emulaterecognize. any help would be appreciated. Below is the code im using.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace HotKeyApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //initialize speech recognizer
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new     System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        //initialize grammer builder
        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        //choices will contain the words from the first column
        Choices jargon = new Choices();
        //words will contain the array to give choices
        string[] words;
        //A speech recognition grammar is a set of rules or constraints that define what a speech recognition engine can recognize as meaningful input.
        Grammar g;

    private int columns = 2;
    private int rows;
    Dictionary<string, string> HotKeys = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ping");
        //to implement loop through the words array if the match call approporaite method
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (e.Result.Text == words[i])
            {
                MessageBox.Show(words[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get number of rows/words
        rows = Convert.ToInt32(txtNum.Text);
        //words length is equal to number of rows
        words = new string[rows];

        GenerateTable(columns, rows);

    }
    private void GenerateTable(int columnCount, int rowCount)
    {
        //Clear out the existing row and column styles
        myGridView.Rows.Clear();
        myGridView.Columns.Clear();

        myGridView.Columns.Add("WordColumn", "Word");
        myGridView.Columns.Add("HotKeyColumn", "HotKey");

        //loop as many times as need to create the rows
        for (int y = 0; y < rowCount; y++)
        {
            myGridView.Rows.Add();
        }
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in myGridView.Rows)
        {
            string Instructions = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string Command = r.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            HotKeys.Add(Instructions, Command);
            words[i] = Instructions;
            i++;
        }
        //give jargon the words array
        jargon.Add(words);
        //give the grammer builder the jargon choices
        gb.Append(jargon);
        //build grammer, load grammer, enable voice recognition
        g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        sre.LoadGrammarAsync(g);

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognized);
        //set sre to use default audio device
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        MessageBox.Show("Recognition enabled");
        // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
        //sre.EmulateRecognize("Hello");
    }
}
}
```

tried converting it to a console application and its working but i need it in a windows forms application. here is the console code:

```
class Program
    {
        static SpeechRecognitionEngine sre;
        //words will contain the array to give choices
        static string[] words;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //initialize speech recognizer
        sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        //initialize grammer builder
        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        //choices will contain the words from the first column
        Choices jargon = new Choices();
        //A speech recognition grammar is a set of rules or constraints that define what a speech recognition engine can recognize as meaningful input.
        Grammar g;

        string input;

        Console.WriteLine("Input words seperated by comma ,");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        words = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string s in words)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        //give jargon the words array
        jargon.Add(words);
        //give the grammer builder the jargon choices
        gb.Append(jargon);
        //build grammer, load grammer, enable voice recognition
        g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        sre.LoadGrammarAsync(g);
        //set sre to use default audio device
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognized);

        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
    static void SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Recognized Word");
        //to implement loop through the words array if the match call approporaite method
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            if (e.Result.Text == words[i])
            {
                Console.WriteLine(words[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than give an incomplete Windows Forms UI, could you try to reproduce this in a minimal console app? I suspect that would be far easier for us to try out.

Comment: ill try but im not that familiar with console. in the mean time all the ui has is 1 text box, 2 buttons and a gridview. btnCreate gets the number from the text box to populate the rows. btnSubmit uses the grid data column 1 till now to give the recognizer the words it should recognize.

Comment: The problem is that to go from the code you've posted to reproducing the problem is likely to take quite a long time. With a console app we'd be able to copy, paste, compile and run.

Comment: managed to convert it and it worked! any idea why it doesnt work in the forms version? updated the question with the console version

Comment: I'd have to look in more detail, but if you've got one working and one not, you should be able to look carefully in the debugger at differences.

Comment: i think the problem is because the .speechRecognized is in the button click. i need something that can wait for the input